# pyodbc with special characters

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, character-encoding, pyodbc

I have the following sql

```
select * from table
where "column" = 'ĚČÍ'
```

which works fine when committed directly to the database (in my case Microsoft SQL Server 2016).

If I use (in python)

```
import pyodbc

ex_str= """select * from table
         where "column" = (?)"""
str2insert= ('ĚČÍ')
 
conn = pyodbc.connect(cstring)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(ex_str,str2insert)
content = cur.fetchall()
```

I get no result although ĚČÍ is definetly an entry in the database column

I added

```
conn.setencoding("utf-8")
```

encoded and decoded the str2insert with latin utf-8 etc. and added

```
cstring = cstring + ";convert_unicode=True"
```

but nothing worked.
There seems to be an issue with pyodbc and special characters. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Verify that your python source file (.py file) is indeed UTF-8 encoded. Also, don't use `conn.setencoding("utf-8")` for SQL Server ODBC; it is not applicable. (SQL Server ODBC and the server instance communicate using UTF-16LE, not UTF-8.)

Comment: What's the actual data type and collation of the column in the database? If it's `nchar` or `nvarchar` you should be fine with the Python fixups already mentioned. If it's `char` or `varchar`, though... E-Charon, C-Charon, I-Acute seem to be common to iso-8859-2/Windows codepage 1250. Are you using a cp1250 collation in SQL Server? e.g.: `select * from sys.fn_helpcollations() where [name] like '%cp1250%'`

Comment: After googleing a bit more I think the issue might be related to my pyodbc version which is 4.0.30. As I have no admin rights I cant update it easily. conerning columns its varchar. I will check the adjusted select.